# Spark filter + map vs flatMap

Tags: scala, apache-spark, persistence, rdd

In spark when computing an RDD I was wondering if for example I have a RDD[Either[A,B]] and I want to obtain the RDD[A] and the RDD[B] basically I've found 2 approaches :

1. `map` + `filter`

   ```
   val rddA = rddEither.filter(_.isLeft).map(case Left(a) => a)
   val rddB = rddEither.filter(_.isRight).map(case Right(b) => b)
   ```
2. `flatMap`

   ```
   val rddA = rddEither.flatMap { case Left(a) => Some(a) }
   val rddB = rddEither.flatMap { case Right(b) => Some(b) }
   ```

If the flatMap more efficient? since there would require potentially less computation?

And other question - is it good to persist the RDD to speed up execution I mean the rddEither because I will compute 2 operation starting from that source or Spark will take care of that?

Comment: Note that there's also [collect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD).

Comment: @DarkAngeL   Can you share the complete code for RDDEither, have not seen this before

Comment: My question was general , what is in general the best approach, because filter has to be executed over all the dataset the map has to be executed from the dataset size in output from the filter so the filter + map in my opinion is more time consuming of flatMap because it has to be executed just for the dataset size . Is this correct?  The source of RDDEither can be whatever it's just a RDD[Either[A,B]]

Comment: @DarkAngeL  not completely sure, but I understand that since Spark builds a DAG of the computation before running it, it made some optimizations, like doing only one iteration with all the computations _(instead of one by transformation)_, if that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Probably [`collect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@collect[U](f:PartialFunction[T,U])(implicitevidence$29:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]) would be a little bit more clear. *(and maybe will take less computation, but I don't think that would have a big impact on performance)*.

```
 val rddA = rddEither.collect { case Left(a) => a }
 val rddB = rddEither.collect { case Right(b) => b }
```

> "And other question: is good to persist the rdd to speed up execution i mean the rddEither because i will compute 2 operation starting from that source or spark will take care of that?"

Spark won't take care of that, spark is Lazy, that means that for each operation it will recompute everything it needs to give the result - unless there is a cache somewhere.
However, adding a cache don't necessarily will increase performance, since if you want  it to be fast you would need to keep it in memory only which can hurt performance of other operations since you would have less memory. And if you save it in disk to reduce memory usage then the time taken to read an deserialize the data from disk could be the same or greater than the time to recompute the original **RDD**. Thus, you may need to benchmark multiple options to decide which will be better.

Note: [this](https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/) is a great post about the memory management in spark, it may be worth reading for tuning cache.

Comment: Yes if the code was only like that ofc nothing will be executed because they are just "transformations" and there is not a following action. But my example was in general suppose there is a rddA.save and a rddB.save by save I mean a persistence in a file or DB. So I just wanted to know if in general is better to flatmap instead of filter + map when u want to get filter out some records and transform the input to another type?

Comment: @DarkAngeL, I think I answered both questions... but I'm not an english native speaker - so maybe I didn't made myself clear. For the first question, I believe any approach will take more or less the same time, since spark can optimize it - thus, the point is which one is more clear, and IMHO `collect` is the winner. For the second question, what I mean was that `cache` may increase performance, may not, or even may decrease it; that depends on your specific problem - thus, the best idea always is to benchmark all variations.

Comment: Note that is `collect(PartialFunction): RDD`, not to be confused with `collect(): Array`.